# How can I show load content while my webpage is loading and hide this content when the page is fully loaded?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I made a nice loading animation with CSS and JS/JQuery. It features a white line turning around into a coloured circle. It works perfectly fine in a seperated html, but now i wanna include it on my webpage.  There is a general script linked to the HTML called script.js. The script for making the animation work is called animation.js. This is my code so far:

```
<div class="loading">
    <div id="colouredCircle">
        <div id="whiteCircle"></div>
        <div id="line"></div>
    </div>
</div>
<script src="animation/animaton.js"></script>
<div class="contents">
    ...
</div>
```

I want to show the div.loading, while the document is still loading. When the document is fully loaded, i want to hide that div.loading, and show the actual content of my HTML page (div.contents). Anyone any idea how to do this? I'm kinda new to JS/JQuery.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use this script. In this javascript your template append to body while loading. after that it's remove from body

```js
var tmpl = '<div id="loading" class="loading">' +
  '    <div id="colouredCircle">' +
  '<div id="whiteCircle"></div>' +
  '<div id="line"></div>' +
  '</div>' +
  '</div>';
var loading = {
  start: function() {
    document.body.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', tmpl);
  },
  complete: function() {
    var loading = document.getElementById("loading");
    loading.remove(loading);
  }
};
loading.start();
document.addEventListener("readystatechange", function() {
  if (document.readyState === "complete") {
    loading.complete();
  }
});
```